# Is there any way to get all points which was drawin on matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Hi
I was wondering if there is any way to get all points which was drawn on Matlab plot. Let's say that I drawn one line on plot and to draw this line I used just two points - matlab ploter connected these points and I get a line. Is there any way to get all the points which are on that line, without saving this plot to file ??

Answer (score 1):

If you plot a line from two points, e.g. `plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2])`, the easiest way to get all the plots on the line is to calculate them directly.

```
nPts = 100; %# number of points on the line you want

%# listOfPoints is a 2-by-nPts array with all the points on the line
listOfPoints = [x1:(x2-x1)/(nPts-1):x2;y1:(y2-y1)/(nPts-1):y2];
```

Comment: Yes of course , but I just gave a simple example. I will need to extract some more complex shapes in the future.

Comment: @image: could you explain further what you're trying to do? MATLAB, unlike mathematica, is one where the plotting is done explicitly. i.e., you say "plot these points". The exceptions are primitive graphics directives and contour lines and the like. So a little more info would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the points you are looking for through basic linear regression. Feed in your x and y variables to Matlab's **regression** function and it calculates the coefficients of the line of plot(x,y). With the line equation set up, you can feed in a list of new x variables and it will calculate the corresponding y values.

```
x=[x1; x2];
y=[y1; y2];
b = regress(y,[ones(length(x),1) x])
new_y=b(1)+b(2)*[new_x1:new_x2]
```